# Copying a range remotely

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I've got a table named FOO with the column `("Porc" |- 3 7 15 50 15 7 3)` and I'm copying the numbers to another table, shown below. I'm doing it the hard way, cell for cell, but I was wondering if there is a way to copy that range of the remote table (A2 to the bottom) in a single command.

```
  | Pr (%) | ROE de A | ROE de B |
  |--------+----------+----------|
  |      3 |   -11.43 |   -34.29 |
  |      7 |       0. |   -11.43 |
  |     15 |     3.43 |       0. |
  |     50 |      12. |    17.14 |
  |     15 |    20.57 |    34.29 |
  |      7 |      24. |    41.14 |
  |      3 |    30.86 |    54.86 |
  |--------+----------+----------|
  |  Média |    11.86 |    16.41 |
  | Desvio |     8.37 |    17.61 |
  #+TBLFM: @2$1=remote(FOO, A2)::@3$1=remote(FOO, A3)::@4$1=remote(FOO, A4)::etc
```

Thanks

Comment: There might be a non org-mode specific solution. Perhaps you could explain in more detail what you are trying to do? The desired Before and After states would help, as would showing the table FOO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your answer is in the org-mode manual:

> $3 = remote(FOO, @@#$2)
>
> copy column 2 from table FOO into
>   column 3 of the current table For the
>   second example, table FOO must have at
>   least as many rows as the current
>   table. Inefficient for large number of
>   rows.

Answer (score 0):

## A Kind of Corollary: Copying all fields in a given *row*

So just as:

```
$3 = remote(FOO, @@#$2)
```

copies all the fields from a given *column* (col2) into column three of the new table, then:

```
@3 = remote(FOO, @1$$#)
```

copies all the fields from a given *row* (row1) into *row* 3.

There's something about how this standard reference form `@r$c` interacts with the `@#` and `$#` notation that makes this seem a bit abstruse. e.g. this is all the **org** manual has to say about this remote reference syntax:

> `@#` and `$#` can be used to get the row or column number of the field where the formula result goes.

Umm…?

Posting this example here because I found it all a bit mystifying and hope this helps some else save a few minutes when dealing with *rows* and tables in the awesome **org-mode**

Comment: To the extent that this question boils down to, "how do I copy a range remotely?" (per the subject header), then it is inaccurate to state this does not provide an answer. But I get your point, tersely delivered as it is. What would have been more helpful--considering that I *cannot* add a comment requesting clarification about copying rows vs. columns--would be to suggest http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer as a resource.